# How do I perform IQueryable requests in MongoDB?

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongodb-query, iqueryable

I'm trying to connect some framework that is based on IQueryable interface (i.e. OData if you wonder).

My current problem can be described using following snippet:

```cs
var queryable = database.GetCollection<MyItems>("myItems").AsQueryable();
var count1 = queryable.Select(x => x.Order.StateInfo).Count();
// var count2 = queryable.Select(x => x.Order).Select(x => x.StateInfo).Count();
```

This code works but if you uncomment the last line you get:

```
System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MyApp.Common.Models.StateInfo]' 
cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[MyApp.Common.Models.StateInfo]' of method
 'Int32 Count[StateInfo](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[MyApp.Common.Models.StateInfo])' (Parameter 'arg0')
   at System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionUtils.ValidateOneArgument(MethodBase method, ExpressionType nodeKind, Expression arguments, ParameterInfo pi, String methodParamName, String argumentParamName, Int32 index)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(MethodInfo method, Expression arg0)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression1.Rewrite(Expression instance, IReadOnlyList`1 args)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.Transformer.Visit(Expression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.Transformer.Transform(Expression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.MongoQueryProviderImpl`1.Prepare(Expression expression)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.MongoQueryProviderImpl`1.Translate(Expression expression)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.MongoQueryProviderImpl`1.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.MongoQueryable.CountAsync[TSource](IMongoQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

It seems that driver tries to perform some operations in-memory, dropping the whole `IQueryable` thing, so all the subsequent calls fail (like Select/Where/...). Query with two subsequent `Select`'s or `Select/Where` pair get efficiently poisoned and cannot be used anywhere. For example:

```cs
var queryable = database.GetCollection<MyItems>("myItems").AsQueryable();
var count1 = queryable.Select(x => x.Order).Where(x => x.StateInfo != null).Count(); 
// System.InvalidOperationException: '{document}.StateInfo is not supported.'
```

What can I do about it? Maybe I can report it somewhere?

Comment: What does `GetCollection<MyItems>` return? Is it `IQueryable<MyItems>`? Why then do you use `AsQueraybel()`? Is the `Order` of `MyItem` in a separate table? What is the relation between `MyItems` and `Orders`? If it is in a separate table does it work if you do the join yourself?

Comment: There is no tables, it's a mongo document. Here is API that I use: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.5/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_MongoDatabase_GetCollection_1.htm

Comment: Ok, now I see. GetCollection is a method that returns access to one table in Mongo. `GetCollection<MyType>` returns access to the table that contains rows of MyType records. The `AsQueryable()` is not an extension method of IEnumerable, but an extension method of MongoCollection. You can get access to the table of MyItems. Are Orders part of MyItems, or does a MyItem have zero or more Orders? In database terms: is there a one-to-many (or maybe many-to-many) relation between Orders and MyItems?

Comment: Maybe you misunderstand document DB conception: there is no relations there or anything. Document is stored as a whole, you can imagine it as serializes JSON array in `.json` file on the disk.  You can access any entry and you get the whole object tree, you don't have joins, tables and stuff. The only difference is mongo performs queries quicker than you could implement with naive JSON file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB C# Driver just partially supports `IQueryable` because it's too hard to implement all cases with MongoDB aggregation pipeline.

So I'm not surprised if version 2.10 doesn't support `Select` out of another `Select` and `Where` out of `Select`.

Can't find any info about this in current documentation but here from v1 doc:

> Select is used to project a new result type from the matching documents. A projection must typically be the last operation (with a few exceptions like Distinct, Max and Min).

Using `IQueryable` is limited to basic methods described [here](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.10/reference/driver/crud/linq/).
And [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/tests/MongoDB.Driver.Tests/Linq/MongoQueryableTests.cs) you can find `IQueryable` tests, where again I can't find `.Select().Select()`.